# Multiple sub-menus and scrolls

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, submenu

In Wordpress i created a menu with sub menus and i want to scroll down so the menus are not going to be so big. so i add

> Blockquote

.sub-menu li:hover ul and then overflow-y

> Blockquote

But only the first submenu becomes a scrolling on. If i have submenu in a submenu then the first submenu doesn't work..

check what i mean here http://www.intereuropetravel.com

Comment: I think you want tick marks to show code or { } instead of those block-quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read your rule from right to left.

```
.sub-menu li:hover ul
```

This says "for any `ul` within an `li:hover` which is within a `.sub-menu` - { apply these rules }

I can't tell exactly what you want - but I think your selector is not doing what you intend. - so write out what you want to happen, and think about it from right to left.

*The only reason why WordPress is relevant, is that it gives you some default classes for your menu.*

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>List item
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sub menu item
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>etc
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                             <li>etc</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, this is some pretty gnarly nesting and, I'm just going to say - that maybe you should rethink this approach, but otherwise - I suggest you build out more specific selectors for each level and control them independently. In WordPress admin under menu - you can reveal a field that will allow you to give unique classes to each of these levels with which you can target more easily.

in your case, you can probably put

`.menu-main-menu-container li:hover ul {}` -

which would be --- "any list inside of any li in your container {}"

maybe even:

`.menu-main-menu-container li:hover > ul {}`

which would be --- "any list directly inside of any li in your container {}"

Comment: wellness & spa > wellness packages     ---- is the only area where it's not all buggy and seems to do what you want.

Comment: Hello :) thanx This is not my design and the owner wants it like this.. The problem is that the menu is generated from the template. How would i write the specific selector in css?

Comment: Do you have access to the CSS? The selector is above these comments in the answer.

Comment: well - what does it do? Did you add it in the right place? have you tried viewing it in developer tools?

Comment: Have you tried giving them special classes like i suggest in the wordpress admin?

Comment: Should i give to everything or the only to the ones i need ?

Comment: I would give a special class to each sub menu so that you can target them and be sure you have full control over each.